# JS comparing innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

Working on a project for class.  I am trying to pass two `<li>` elements into the function below, one at a time.  Then, I am trying to compare the `innerHTML`, which is an `<i>` element.  If it matches, I call one function.  If not, i call another.

But, when I run it, it does not work.  I put the `console.log`s in the code as a test, and they never fire.  Any idea what is going on?

```
gameDeck.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   incrementMove();
   const pick = e.target;
   display(pick);
   addCards(pick)
})

function display(card) {
    card.className += " open show";
}

let pick1, pick2;

function addCards(openCard){

  if (!pick1) {
    let pick1 = openCard;
  } else if (!pick2) {
    let pick2 = openCard
    console.log(pick1)
    console.log(pick2)
    if (pick1.innerHTML == pick2.innerHTML) {
        match();
    } else {
        reset();
    }
  }
}
```

I did see some related questions on this topic, but they are all using jquery, which I do not know.

Comment: Can you also provide how this is used? with what data?

Comment: have you forgot to invoke your function?

Comment: Remove the `let`s in `addCards()`

Comment: @KevinB:  I added the additional code, as to how the function is called.  Basically, I see the problem, the variables are getting reset to undefined each time, but I do not know how to solve that.  I need to store the first element, then store the second, then compare the two for a match on the innerHTML.

Comment: @HughB An answer exists on this question that explains how to resolve that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> let pick1 = openCard;
> ```

You redeclare `pick1` *inside* the function.

This creates a new variable that masks the global variable of the same name.

Each time you run the function, you get a new `pick1` and a new `pick2`, both of which are `undefined`.

Consequently, you'll always hit the first half of the `if/else`.

Remove the `let` declarations from those two variables inside the function.

---

I'm fed up with the OP making comments that this won't work instead of actually trying it.

```js
gameDeck.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   const pick = e.target;
   addCards(pick)
})


let pick1, pick2;

function addCards(openCard){

  if (!pick1) {
    pick1 = openCard;
  } else if (!pick2) {
    pick2 = openCard
    console.log(pick1)
    console.log(pick2)
    if (pick1.innerHTML == pick2.innerHTML) {
        match();
    } else {
        reset();
    }
  }
}

function match() {
    alert("They match");
}

function reset() {
    alert("They don't match");
}
```

```html
<div id="gameDeck">
<button>One</button>
<button>Two</button>
<button>Three</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the rest of the code so you can see what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: but what I am trying to do is pass in the value from the addEventListener event each time; the first time, assign the value to pick1, the second time, assign the value to pick2, then compare.  I do not see how to get around that issue.

Comment: @HughB — You do what I said to do in the last line of this answer.

Comment: but if I do that, I will never assign the values to them I am trying to compare, which are the values from the click events in the above addEventListener.  I guess that is the question: how do I assign the values from two independent click events, in order to compare them, without overwriting.  I actually pushed them to a list in an earlier version, but that was not workable for another reason later in the program.  I need them to be two variables, not list items.

Comment: "but if I do that, I will never assign the values to them I am trying to compare, which are the values from the click events in the above addEventListener" — What? Yes you will.

Comment: pick1 and pick2 are assigned the values in openCard inside the function (those two statements you are talking about), nowhere else.  the let pick1, pick2 outside the function was intended simply to create the variables.  Please look up in the code, to the event listener, where the addCards function is invoked.

Comment: @HughB — "pick1 and pick2 are assigned the values in openCard inside the function (those two statements you are talking about), nowhere else. " — I don't think you understand what remove "let" means. It doesn't mean "Remove the whole line that starts with 'let'".

Comment: You are correct. I think that did the trick, once I grasped that clarification.  It's not that I was "saying it wouldn't work" without actually trying it, I simply misunderstood our statement.